# Listing all existing screens on AWS ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I am aware that this has been asked several times over here and to list all screens I need to execute to command `screens -ls`

However, just for the experiment I created a screen -> Ran `npm start` command over there to launch my application -> closed the terminal -> logged on the the server -> Logged back in and ran `screens -ls` and I see `No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-ubuntu`

Does that mean my previously created screen was terminated the moment I close the terminal? Strangely, it should not happen and the screen session should be active all the time unless you manually terminate the screen.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for posting the question in haste. I figure out what was the problem.

I changed the instance type on my EC2 running instance and thus had to restart the EC2 instance which causes all the screen to be killed.